# Find parent of a JPanel

Tags: java, jpanel, parent

I am trying to change size of the window holding my App, It is installed into a larger App to which I have little access & understanding.

I am trying to find a suitable "parent" and set its size, however, when I inspect the parent it appears to be **null**.

myPanelClass is a very large extension of a JPanel. So I cannot supply it here.

```
public void display(myPanelClass starterModule) {

starterModule.getParent().setSize(new Dimension(300,800));

}
```

Is there another way to find parents or ancestors?

Comment: Try http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getWindowAncestor(java.awt.Component)

Comment: When the parent is `null`, then this means that the panel has not yet been added to a container (or already been removed again). When are you calling this method? (Also, note that this approach for changing the window size in this form sounds ... dubius, to say the least. Maybe you can elaborate what you actually want to achieve)

Comment: I have an App that is usually shown in a small window. I need to show a larger image (in same window) at one point. I want to be able to grow window size temporarily. Easy to do if you have jFrame ref - but I do not.